# CSV with tab as quote character

Tags: java, csv

I have tried several CSV parsers for Java but non of them handled the following line properly:

```
String str = "\tvalue1\t,,\tv1,",',v3\t,value2"
```

The format is **comma** separated with TAB as **escape** character. Part of fields empty, part not escaped.

Any suggestion for parser which handles this format good?

For example I would expect that the above string will be parsed as:

```
value1
null
v1,",',v3
value2
```

But it's producing the following:

```
value1
 null
 v1
 "
 '
 v3
 value2
```

---

Java Example:

```
import java.lang.String;
import com.univocity.parsers.csv.CsvParser;
import com.univocity.parsers.csv.CsvParserSettings;

public class StamMain {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String str = "\tvalue1\t,,\tv1,',",v3\t,value2";
        System.out.println(str);
        CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings();
        settings.getFormat().setQuote('\t');
        CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);
        String[] fields = parser.parseLine(str);
        for (String f : fields)
            System.out.println(f);
    }
}
```

The best results achieved if TAB replaced by quote, but quoting quotes is interesting task by itself.

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: Hey @Robert. What *is* the parsed result? (You've said what the right answer should be, but we don't know what the parser is actually producing.) That will help diagnose the problem. :)

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: Just saying, `coma` should be `comma` in your question. Just so people take you more seriously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) can handle it just fine.

```
String str = "\tvalue1\t,,\tv1,\",',v3\t,value2";
CSVFormat csvFormat = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withQuote('\t');
for (CSVRecord record : CSVParser.parse(str, csvFormat))
    for (String value : record)
        System.out.println(value);
```

*Output*

```
value1

v1,",',v3
value2
```

You can even add `.withNullString("")` to get that null value, if you want.

```
value1
null
v1,",',v3
value2
```

Very flexible CSV parser.

Comment: I like this solution. Wanted to post Common CVS as well :)

Answer (score 1):

Works with [Super CSV](https://super-csv.github.io/super-csv/examples_reading.html)

```
ICsvListReader reader = new CsvListReader(
    new FileReader("weird.csv"), 
    CsvPreference.Builder('\t', ',', "\r\n").build() 
);

List<String> record = reader.read();

for(String value : record)
  System.out.println(value);
```

Output:

```
value1
null
v1,",',v3
value2
```

Comment: Waiting for code example with the link to a library.

Comment: Followup question:
Can CsvListReader accept Reader as source and not file?

Comment: @RobertNavado It *is* accepting a `Reader` in the example here. A `FileReader`.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this line before parsing to get the result you expect:

`settings.trimValues(false);`

This is required because by default the parser removes white spaces around delimiters, but your "quote" character happens to be a white space. Regardless, this is something the parser should handle. I opened [this bug report](https://github.com/uniVocity/univocity-parsers/issues/100) to have it fixed in the next version of uniVocity-parsers.

Comment: Already fixed on version [2.2.0-SNAPSHOT](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/univocity/univocity-parsers/2.2.0-SNAPSHOT/univocity-parsers-2.2.0-20160622.041336-7.jar). Notice that by default values will be trimmed, so you will get 'value2' instead of ' value2 '. If you still want ' value2 ' disable trim.

Comment: One additional config that I should make there is to add escape and escape-escape character. It seems I asked incomplete question.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to:

1) Replace all the double quotes in your string with some "good" replacement string that you know won't be in the actual data (e.g. "REPLACE_QUOTES_TEMP")

2) Replace all tabs with double quotes.

3) Run the parser as normal.

4) Replace back the "REPLACE_QUOTES_TEMP" strings (or whatever you chose), in the individual fields, with the actual double quote.

Comment: Well,  this the way it's working now, but the actual string is much longer and every replace is performance penalty. This code is running for millions of rows

Comment: Why go through all that when there are multiple CSV parsers that can do it, e.g. [SuperCSV](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37956382/5221149) and [Apache Commons CSV](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37956606/5221149)?

Comment: @Andreas That would certainly be ideal, but the OP mentioned that he had tried several parsers that didn't fit his data.

Answer (score -2):

The String "\tvalue1\t,,\tv1,",',v3\t,value2" is not valid. to include '"' as character you need to write '\"'.

For parsing this code should work:

String st = "\tvalue1\t,,\tv1,\",',v3\t,value2";

String[] arr = st.split("\t");

Comment: @adas That won't work either: What about `"aaa,bbbb,\t ccc, ddd \t"`  (The OP would want 3 values and that would produce 4)

Comment: aaa
bbbb

 ccc
 ddd

Comment: The argument inside split() specifies that "split by all \t and ,". Thanks.

Comment: Which is wrong: The OP would want ["aaa", "bbbb", " ccc, ddd "] (3 values)